# Initialize string with position of string vector

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I've a problem with this function. I want to initialize a string at the position i in a string vector.
But i'm getting this error Message:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
 basic_string()
 basic_string(const std::allocator<char> &)
 basic_string(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)
 basic_string(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, unsigned int)
 basic_string(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &, unsigned int, unsigned int, const std::allocator<char> &)
 basic_string(const char *, unsigned int, const std::allocator<char> &)
 basic_string(const char *, const std::allocator<char> &)
 basic_string(unsigned int, char, const std::allocator<char> &)
```

The function:

```
void File::readBinaryTreeHelper(Node *&anchor, std::vector<std::string> list, int* i){

    std::string g = list[i];

    readBinaryTreeHelper(anchor->Vater, list, i+1);
    readBinaryTreeHelper(anchor->Mutter, list, i+1);

}
```

Comment: I think this is unrelated, but `i` is a pointer, so `list[i];` is questionable.

Comment: dereference the `i`. `g = list[*i]`, or just pass it by reference `int& i`

Comment: The pointer there should be a totally different set of error messages: https://godbolt.org/z/SFePBy . If I remove the pointer, no errors. Could we get a [mre]?

Comment: `Invalid arguments '` -- this looks like an incomplete error message. What is the full error message? (Copy-and-paste as text is preferred.) To which character in your source code does your compiler attribute this error? (Error messages typically contain a line number and character position. Many also include the line in the message, followed by a line pointing to the character. Copying that would be good.)